# books api same book different languages

Tags: internationalization, google-books

I'm looking at google Books API Documentation but I can't figure out if it's possible to recognize that 2 editions in different languages are of the same book.

For example:

Kafka on the shore (English)
http://books.google.it/books?id=A08c2Ep7QbYC

Kafka sulla spiaggia (Italian)
http://books.google.it/books?id=cyDyATFIxo8C

Developing a multilingual web application it would be useful to group such editions. If not in google books, does someone know an API that allows to do this?

Answer (score 1):

[WorldCat](http://www.worldcat.org/) has the data for various "editions" of any specific title. The editions query covers the languages as well:

http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/62879613/editions

There is also an [API](http://oclc.org/developer/services/worldcat-search-api) available, but apparently it's not free to use for personal and commercial purposes.

Comment: Thank you Shervin, I totally missed WorldCat. You're right, the full API's not free, but there's a cut down version http://oclc.org/developer/services/worldcat-basic-api I'll give it a try as soon as they approve my key request.